# Connect to router at home without password

Tags: windows-7, windows, router, wireless-router

Here is my situation:

I just installed Windows 7 in a new partition, and have Windows Vista installed in the old partition. We have a router at home that belongs to my roommate, who is on a trip and won't come back until February. For some reason, he didn't want to give me the password but instead, just came and typed it in my computer when I was using my Windows Vista installation, so I can connect through that installation since the password is saved.

I tried to export the connection profile to an XML file from command line with instructions I found somewhere on the web, and then imported it from my Windows 7 installation, but then it asked me for the password again.

I remember once, trying to connect to that router from some laptop, I believe, it asked me to press some button on the router. I believe this is some kind of alternative to using a password, but Windows 7 is just asking me to enter the password.

I just sent my roommate an email asking for the password, but I'm not sure if he will write back. Probably the password contains something he doesn't want people to know.

So my question is, considering that this router is here at home, and that my Windows Vista knows the router's password, is there any way I can connect to the internet through my Windows 7 installation?

Comment: Make and model of router might allow some additional answers.

Comment: Do you mean the router password or the WiFi encryption key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reveal wifi passwords in windows with a program like [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html).

Run the program in your Vista install and it should reveal the password.

Comment: Yep. If it works for you, please mark the post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mozilla Firefox, and you "saved" the password when logging into the maintenance site, 192.168.1.1, then you can simply go to the Firefox tab at the top in the browser window, choose options, go to Security tab, then choose Saved Passwords, then locate the http://192.168.1.1, and then choose Show Passwords. Hit yes if prompted, and voila. You can see all the passwords. Then take that password and type it in when you load up the Windows 7.

But remember, for my method, you need to have the following:

Mozilla Firefox
Used the http://192.168.1.1 site
Typed in the username and password
Hit "remember password" when prompted by Firefox
Still be able to access this information

Comment: I think he just wants to use the wifi connection in his Win7 installation. I don't think he wants to login as admin on the router.

Comment: Besides, you don't have to (and it's bad practice to) use the same password for the admin page and the wifi key.